# Is it possible to use the contents of a variable as the name of an array vb.net?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, variables

Just trying to make multiple arrays that are names after the contents of a variable. I need a new array every time the user of my program creates a new folder to store information about the files in the folder. For example, if the user creates a folder called "My Holiday", I want the name of the array to be called "My Holiday". Is this possible? If so how do i do it.

Comment: you can use a dictionary<string, array) instead... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The compiler needs to know variables (name, types) at compile time.  How would you write code referencing that array since it too would not know the name